# Looking for a Solution, methodology design, requirements and needs, implementation, and how to test

Tags: azure, vmware-workstation

Trying to prevent employees from accessing company vital records. What would be a good methodology design for access control and authorization for Azure or VMware?
The company experienced employees gaining access to sensitive data like accounting ledgers, operational costs, strategic overviews, customer, and employee contact information. This information had private customer details and trade secrets. The owner Mr. Davis was furious that without proper access could view the data. He wants a better access control system to be put in place so that only authorized employees can view vital information and other employees can view the information they need to take care of day-to-day operations. The desired outcome is to provide the best access control system for the company's needs and verify that only authorized workers can view vital information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard about Azure Policies?
Here's everything you need to know about this entity
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview#:~:text=Azure%20Policy%20evaluates%20resources%20in,(sometimes%20called%20a%20policySet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview#:%7E:text=Azure%20Policy%20evaluates%20resources%20in,(sometimes%20called%20a%20policySet)).